# Reconversión de variables categóricas en numéricas en RStudio

Tags: r

Necesito convertir valores categóricos (por. ej una variable que se denomina, frecuencia de asistencia a servicios religiosos, cuyas respuestas son: `Once a week`, `more than once a week`, etc) y necesito recodificar o convertir estas etiquetas en valores numéricos (Ej. `More than once a week=1`), para poder hacer luego un análisis factorial.

A modo de ejemplo de los datos:

```
set.seed(1)
levels <- c('never', 'once a week', 'more than once a week')
df <- data.frame(fsar = sample(levels, 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Bienvenido Mariana Sendra a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Hola Mariana, bienvenida. Te sugiero revisar la función `psych::fa.poly()`, para análisis factorial de variables ordinales. Más allá de ahorrarte la conversión de factor a numérico lo importante es que tiene supuestos más débiles de distribución subyacente continua para tus variables. `fa.poly` hace el análisis factorial sobre variables ordinales usando una matriz de correlaciones policóricas en lugar de una matriz de covarianza, como lo haría si pasas variables numéricas. Técnicamente es una mejor alternativa. Mejor aún un modelo item respuesta o de clases latentes.

Answer (score 1):

No está de más mencionar que se trata de una variable "ordinal", dónde el orden claramente importa. Cómo "recodificar" esta variable va a depender de la naturaleza de la misma, básicamente si se trata de una `character` o de un `factor`.

Lo primero es definir un vector con nuestros `levels` obviamente en orden, luego, teniendo la columna `fsar` como una simple cadena, para convertir estos valores en una código numérico podríamos hacer:

```
levels <- c('never', 'once a week', 'more than once a week')
df$fsar_num <- match(df$fsar, levels)
```

Con `match()` obtenemos el índice del vector `levels` del valor que se corresponde con cada valor de `df$fsar`. La otra forma es convertir la columna en un `factor` ordenado.

```
df$fsar_factor = factor(df$fsar, levels = levels)
df$fsar_num2 <- as.integer(df$fsar_factor)
```

En realidad no necesitamos crear nuevas columnas, es solo a efectos didácticos. Con `factor(df$fsar, levels = levels)` convertimos la columna original en un factor que respeta el orden ya definido en `levels`. Por lo que simplemente convirtiendo la columna en un entero, con `as.integer()` obtenemos los códigos numéricos que buscamos. Esto último nos sirve en el caso en que nuestra columna/variable ya sea un `factor`

Salida final:

```
df
                    fsar fsar_num           fsar_factor fsar_num2
1                  never        1                 never         1
2            once a week        2           once a week         2
3            once a week        2           once a week         2
4  more than once a week        3 more than once a week         3
5                  never        1                 never         1
6  more than once a week        3 more than once a week         3
7  more than once a week        3 more than once a week         3
8            once a week        2           once a week         2
9            once a week        2           once a week         2
10                 never        1                 never         1
```